# Setting the limits of integration in the triple integral for flux

Tags: integration, vector-fields

Let $T$ be the figure bounded by: $y-\sqrt{1-x^2-z^2}=0$, $x^2+z^2=1$, $y-z=2$(green axis is y, blue - z)[image: It looks like]

I need calculate the lateral flow for semi-sphere(that burgundy thing on the image) $\vec a = ..\vec i+..\vec j+..\vec k$(I will not write the formula since it is not important in the question).

**What I've done?**

First of all, I tried to count general flux. I use that $\int\int(\vec a, \vec n)dT=\int\int\int( div\vec a )dx dy dz$. $div\vec a=const$. The main problem is that I can't even imagine, how to set limits of integration in this triple integral. I tried cylindrical coordinate system, where $x=rcos(\phi), y=y, z=rsin(\phi)$, but the same trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The cylindrical coordinates that you chose later is the right approach. If you see the region, $y$ is bound between the sphere and the plane. $x, z$ is bound by cylinder $x^2+z^2 = 1$.

So limits of integration is,

$\sqrt{1-x^2-z^2} \leq y \leq {z+2}, \ 0 \leq x^2+z^2 \leq 1$.

So using cylindrical coordinates as,

$x = r \cos\theta, y = y, z = r\sin\theta$

The limits of integration is,

$\sqrt{1-r^2} \leq y \leq r \sin\theta + 2, 0 \leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

Comment: Are you sure? I still have question. So, I can write it like $\int_{\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{rsin(\phi)}dy\int_{0}^{1}rdr\int_{0}^{2\Pi}d\phi$. What does it mean? "Outer" integral is running on y, so at every "step"(in other words for all y in $[\sqrt{1-r^2},rsin(\phi)]$ we are taking plane X0Z. Speaking about 2 other integrals, they are saying, that we are taking whole circle. If $y>1$ there is no circle, it's a figure like circle, but it's cropped from the bottom. So it's seems to me, that limits for r and $\phi$ can't be a constant value, looks like $\phi$ is changing with $y$. Hope you understand me

Comment: Limits of $y$ are dependent on $r$ and $\theta$. So you have  to integrate wrt $dy$ first then $dr$ or $d\theta$ can be in any order.

Comment: It's hard to realize. Anyway, thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: The way you need to think about it is that take a cylindrical shell along y-axis. At any given $r$ and $\theta$, the bounds that I have given for $y$ gives you the height of the shell along y-axis. All such shells for $0 \leq r \leq 1$ and for $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ will give you the volume of the region.

Comment: Also if you are applying divergence theorem, it will give you flux through the entire closed surface. What is your final objective, to find flux through only the hemi-spherical surface?

Comment: Yes, final goal is to find flux through only the hemi-spherical surface. Guess, that I need to substruct something from the entire flux

Comment: If so, why not apply divergence theorem directly to the spherical surface closing it with a disk at $y = 0$. Then find flux through the disk at $y = 0$ and subtract it. That will give you flux going out of the spherical surface in positive $y$ direction. You will need to reverse the sign as the flux you need is in opposite direction.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Am I right, that flux through the disk at y = 0 is equal to 0?

Comment: It depends on the vector field. I do not know the vector field.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I already figured it out. Thanks a lot again!)

Comment: you are welcome.